# SVG Animation - Reverse and stop after 50px from top

Tags: svg, svg-animate

How can I reverse the SVG animation ... Need to animate from **TOP** to **BOTTOM**?

And I want to stop the round after 50px from top (from 0 to **50px** it has to animate and **stop**)

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
p {
  color: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 500">
<path id="motionPath" fill="none" stroke="#ED1E25" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="10,8" d="M53.738,2243.583
c0,0,53.198-53.916,58.558-133.25S64.321,1976.33,49.655,1954.33s-44.331-55.33-44-122.664
c0.111-22.688,9.666-77.666,48.666-129.333c24.376-32.293,40.667-85.68,41.667-118.678c0,0,3.667-63.012-34.333-114.345
c-10.717-14.478-56.003-66.333-47.001-133c3.597-26.633,11.017-64.334,44.509-107s57.491-91.004,53.133-144.337
c-2.348-28.726-11.975-80.665-59.975-133.665C31.307,928.106-6.345,864.978,8.988,791.978c1.793-8.538,15.666-62.331,44.666-95.998
s47.334-113.995,41.334-147.995c-2.515-14.252-5-58.736-54.042-116.589c-16.472-19.432-39.65-81.737-20.958-134.07
c8.677-24.293,20-51.077,26.5-60.577s34-51.25,38-84.25c1.444-11.916,10.5-87-31-144.584"/>

<circle id="circle" r="10" cx="0" cy="0" fill="tomato" />

<animateMotion
xlink:href="#circle"
dur="5s"
begin="0s"
fill="freeze"
repeatCount="1">
<mpath xlink:href="#motionPath" />
</animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the animation with:

`keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"`

in the animationMotion definition. With these attributes you can also stop the animation and go back to the start. I just added a black line at ~ 50px (50px + the margin on top) and modified the keyPoints that the circle turns at this line. It's

`keyPoints="1;0.952;1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear"`

in your case. That's not the cleanest way, because it's not exactly after 50px, but if you don't want to add a new path, which has the needed length of your animation path, you have to test a little bit.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/df4qt9zz/

Moreover keep in mind that SVG is scalable, so the 50px will be around 100px if the size of the SVG is getting bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification... I got what I want, except need to stop after 50px (or may be different height) which it should not go up again...

Comment: To have it stop, use `keyPoints="1;0.952" keyTimes="0;1"`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't know why I thought it has to turn.